# Conference Sponsorship List

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, conference

Please post conferences you feel StackExchange could sponsor or sponsor users to attend within the sphere of skepticism.

Answer (score 5):

The Amazing Meeting (TAM) - http://www.amazingmeeting.com/

Comment: Plus regional variants, such as TAMOz: http://www.tamaustralia.org/.

Comment: TAM London - http://www.tamlondon.org/

Answer (score 2):

One week too late, but maybe next year: The GWUP-Conference in Vienna. [GWUP, Gesellschaft zur wissenschaftlichen Untersuchung von Parawissenschaften, (Society for Scientific Evaluation of Parasciences)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GWUP)  (Lang: de) and here is a [blog from that organisation](http://blog.gwup.net/category/konferenz-2011/).

I'm sorry, I'm not able to provide something in english and more official looking. It doesn't even look like conference. :) This year, they spent a prize, a golden shelf. There is a german saying 'Brett vor dem Kopf, having a shelve in front of your head', meaning: to be a blockhead. This prize was spent for a film about 'Lichtnahrung', the theory of substitution of food with light.

Answer (score 1):

QED Con - http://www.qedcon.org/

Answer (score 1):

This seems a logical choice:

This is the first announcement of the 6th World Skeptics Congress to be held from May 18 - 20, 2012 in Berlin, Germany,  Hotel Crowne Plaza (Berlin City Centre). The Congress series deals with claims ranging from the paranormal and supernatural to fringe science issues and conspiration theories. Major topics at this event will be science and sseudoscience in education, addressing in particular anti-evolution claims and origin myths, as well as the psychology of risk and benefit perception, addressing alternative medicine as a major sub-topic.

http://www.worldskeptics.org/15-events/skeptics-world-2012/1-early-congress-2012

Comment: Oh, how unfair! Just when I move away there is finally a skeptics’ conference hosted here.

Answer (score 0):

There are national conferences, hosted by the peak skeptics bodies in that country, held around the world. It may be cost-effective to send people to a more local event than, say, Las Vegas.

For example:

- [Australia](http://www.skeptics.com.au)
- [New Zealand](http://www.skeptics.org.nz/SK:SKEPCONFERENCE)
- [Norway](http://www.kritiskmasse.no/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=17)

(Community Wiki: Feel free to add more.)